# Having trouble with QUnit test in ember because of Toast-ui-Editor, cannot find the solution

Tags: ember.js, tui

I'm currently working on an emberJS project, and I have a random global failure whenever I'm running tests (QUnit).
We've been working on it since few days with a colleague, and we found out that it's coming from the Toast UI editor made for ember (https://github.com/evocount/ember-tui-editor)
It hasn't been updated since 7 months, but we have no idea what to do to solve the problem :/

we tried to add a later() method to wait (like a set Timeout) and it's not working
when we comment the willDestroy ember hook inside the TUI component, tests are running completely.
There is no coherent pattern to find out what the problem exactly is! ^^'

Comment: Hello! welcome to ember stack overflow!! <3  
To better help, could you provide what the failure is, and the associated stack trace? Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see [ask]. Then [edit] your question and include the code here in the question, as formatted text (use the `{}` button), as a [mcve]. Links can break, and linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with similar problems.